# python error in decoding base64 string

Tags: python, base64, gzip

I'm trying to unzip a base64 string,

this is the code I'm using

```
def unzip_string(s) :
    s1 = base64.decodestring(urllib.unquote(s))
    sio = StringIO.StringIO(s1)
    gzf = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=sio)
    guff = gzf.read()
    return json.loads(guff)
```

i'm getting error Error: Incorrect padding

where I try to unzip the same string using node.js code it works without a problem.

where:

```
s == H4sIAAAAAAAAA22PW0/CQBCF/8s81wQosdA3TESJhhhb9cHwMN1O6Ybtbt0LhDT97+5yU4yPc+bMnO90YCyyDaSfHRimieQSG4IUaldABC1qbAykHbQsrzWZWokSUumEiMCQ3nJGCy9ADH0EFvWarJ+eHv11v4qgEIptqHyTlovzWes0q9HQ3X87Lh80Msp5gDhqzGlN0or9B1pWU5ldxV72c2/ODg0C7lUXu/U2p8XLpY35+6Mmtsn4WqLILFrnTRUKQxFwk7+fSL23+zX215VD/jE16CeojIzhSi5kpQ6xzVkIz76wuSmHRVINRuVtheMxDuLJJB5Nk5hRMkriaTGJh8MDn5LWv8v3bejzvFjez15/5EsNbuZo7FzpHepyJoTaBWqrHfX9N0/UAJ7qAQAA.bi0I1YDZ3V6AXu6aYTGO1JWi5tE5CoZli7aa6bFtqM4
```

I've seen some suggestions to add '=' and other magic but it just results in the gzip module failing to open the file.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me (Python 3). The padding is indeed important, as you've seen in other answers:

```
import base64
import zlib
import json

s = b'H4sIAAAAAAAAA22PW0/CQBCF/8s81wQosdA3TESJhhhb9cHwMN1O6Ybtbt0LhDT97+5yU4yPc+bMnO90YCyyDaSfHRimieQSG4IUaldABC1qbAykHbQsrzWZWokSUumEiMCQ3nJGCy9ADH0EFvWarJ+eHv11v4qgEIptqHyTlovzWes0q9HQ3X87Lh80Msp5gDhqzGlN0or9B1pWU5ldxV72c2/ODg0C7lUXu/U2p8XLpY35+6Mmtsn4WqLILFrnTRUKQxFwk7+fSL23+zX215VD/jE16CeojIzhSi5kpQ6xzVkIz76wuSmHRVINRuVtheMxDuLJJB5Nk5hRMkriaTGJh8MDn5LWv8v3bejzvFjez15/5EsNbuZo7FzpHepyJoTaBWqrHfX9N0/UAJ7qAQAA.bi0I1YDZ3V6AXu6aYTGO1JWi5tE5CoZli7aa6bFtqM4'

decoded = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(s + b'=')
uncompressed = zlib.decompress(decoded, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
unjsoned = json.loads(uncompressed.decode('utf-8'))

print(unjsoned)
```

The `zlib.decompress(decoded, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)` is a slightly more compact way to un-gzip a byte string.

Comment: you just became my favourite person on the internet :)

Comment: Excellent. You can accept the answer if it's right?

Comment: problem is that now the zlib function fails, where s = H4sIAAAAAAAAA81Q0U7CMBT9l/s8E2SEwd4wihIJITL1wfhwae9cQ9fOtoOQZf9uy0SF8AE+Nfec3nPPOQ1Yh2wD6VsDlhkitcCSIIWiXkMEFRosLaQNVCwrDNlCSw6pqqWMwJLZCkYzD8AQ2ggcmg9yfnq8ffDrbXSm6bYnksJmLzdSsw0FhebP2MK5ehR8uiDCKReK+FIoD66990wvCM1cbAObo7TkCS5sJXE/U7n2DxlID8ypyamP0RmE9t2LdceflRPymLGqDSvQ0s0lTqh7g4wyEdJ1GKuNIeXk/hUdK4ivzlJ88+HyqrucXiqpNnL5P3v6ibAia4VWYfOQoTwCwcgnllf8ep3kvT4f5jgYYC8ejeL+OIkZJf0kHq9HcahDK+e1sn0VTM1ni7vJ0y98kArfhJ2idVNtdmj4REq9C1U4U1PbfgEKKymWwgIAAA==.QbqL60VQGqBsezVFYSdOKv5ZoX+/68tSu7RSQwmpPcY, i get   incorrect header check

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that `s` up to the `==`, and decodes fine with gzip. What is the `.Qbq`... after the `==`?